# jenkins - launch agent from browser button missing

Tags: jenkins, java-11, agent

I am setting up a new jenkins install.  I upgraded to java 11 (maybe that is the reason the launch button is not there).  I did everything recommended online, made sure the TCP ports for inbound agents were set to random.  When setting up a new node I have it set to "launch agent by connecting it to the controller"

[image]

But I can't get the launch icon to show up.  Perhaps because it is java 11 i have to setup the agent another way?  If so how would i set it up?

[image]

Comment: yes, the method to connect the slaves has changed from previous jenkins versions. It no longer has the launch button.  I had to run the command shown in command line

Comment: i can run the command and the master connects to the agent. How do you deal when server reboots or command session is closed?

Comment: I created a windows service.  I dont remember where I found the information but I did write out the steps to set it up if you want me to share

Comment: yes please! some sort of how-to would really help. Thank you!

Comment: I found the tutorial i used, - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8AQTlHoBKc
if your having trouble getting it to work i can send the instructions I wrote up myself, but its pretty much exactly what this guy does